Statically defined List<Field> is not recognized by jOOQ in Repository class
We've got a pattern that has worked in the past for insert statements, but I'm attempting to reuse it for a select statement and seeing what I'd consider to be unexpected behavior. Assume everything that isn't delineated here is correctly defined; I'm trying to keep this brief, not cover the nitty-gritty details.
So I have an entity (all code is Groovy):
class SomeEntity {
    
    static class COLUMNS {
        public static final String COL_1 = 'col_1'
        public static final String COL_2 = 'col_2'
        // ...elided
    }

    static class FIELDS {
        public static final Field<String> COL_1 = DSL.field(COLUMNS.COL_1, String)
        public static final Field<String> COL_2 = DSL.field(COLUMNS.COL_2, String)
        // ...elided
    }

    static List<Field<?>> ENTITY_FIELDS = [FIELDS.COL_1, FIELDS.COL_2]

    @Column(name = COLUMNS.COL_1)
    String col1

    @Column(name = COLUMNS.COL_2)
    String col2
}

(This is severely truncated as a minimal example. There are also Boolean,  LocalDateTime, and BigDecimal Fields.)
And then a repo like this:
@Repository
class SomeEntityRepo {

    DSLContext jooq

    SomeEntityRepo(DSLContext jooq) {
        this.jooq = jooq
    }

    SomeEntity findEntityDate(String id) {
        return jooq.select(ENTITY_FIELDS)
                   .from(table)
                   .where(COL_1.eq(id))
                   .fetchOneInto(SomeEntity)
    }

}

(also truncated, we use constructor injection... there's a join that will happen, etc.)
What I'm seeing is that jOOQ is executing a select * from ... rather than a select col_1, col_2 from .... The minute I move the declaration of ENTITY_FIELDS into the repository class, it works as expected.
The main issue here is that this should actually end up as select table.col_1, table.col_2 from ... because there's a join and, of course, both tables have an id column. I can, of course, define the List<Field> in the repo class, but I have more than one such list, so it's kind of nice to have them declared (and hidden away) in the entity classes. Also, there's another query that's more join-heavy and ultimate what got me hunting down this issue.
Again, using these entity-defined Lists works just fine for insert statements, so I'm confused why they are not recognized correctly by the select. I've read the documentation and noticed that * is substituted when columns are not recognized, but I've even gone so far as to reduce the entity-defined List to just the ID field and it still does a select *.
Am I missing something? Is there a reason for this? Is the behavior caused by jOOQ or is this a Spring issue? This project is using Spring Boot 3.2.2 and jOOQ 3.17.6.

P.S. Update:
I've continued to mess around here and think I may have found a reason for this, but it also boggles my mind. The SomeEntity class also has this going on:
class SomeEntity {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
    public static final org.jooq.Table ENTITY_TABLE = DSl.table(TABLE_NAME)

    public static final org.jooq.Table OTHER_TABLE = DSL.table('other_table')
    // and two more for other entities

    static class FIELDS {
        // previous entries elided
        public static final Field<String> OTHER_ID = DSL.field("$ENTITY_TABLE.other_id") // this is not exactly right, but gives the general idea of what we do in many places
        // repeat for a handful of other fields.
    }
}

If I move those additional entries to the repo class, everything suddenly works as expected (with the ENTITY_FIELDS list in-use). I can leave the "additional Tables" and it's fine. If I also move the additional tables, it starts doing select * again.
I'm going to continue to experiment; these additional tables/fields technically don't belong in SomeEntity, so I'll see if refactoring them, together, works, but I'm not hold my breath given the above information.


Can you please make sure your code is correct (i.e. it compiles)? Otherwise, people might be chasing syntax errors that appear only because you made a wrong example here on Stack Overflow, rather than getting on track to answer your actual question. 2) what's the reason why you're not usting the code generator?


@LukasEder, I'm not sure what to add to make it compile. This is an example based on real, functioning code. As for the code generator, I didn't make that call, but in over 6 years of development, we've never needed it. As far as we're concerned, how jOOQ functions without it is great.

I'm sorry, I didn't realise it was groovy. I don't know how groovy initialises classes, so I'm not sure what went wrong here... The list of fields is probably not yet initialised when you access it, could that be it? The SELECT *  syntax is rendered when 1) you don't have any SELECT clause (e.g. the list is empty) and 2) the from() clause doesn't provide any fields lists (e.g. you're not using the code generator).

Hmm. The list definitely isn't empty (it's statically defined). I have to assume that the way we're doing the "table" in from() does provide field lists since it works in certain ways and not others.
I did just take a look at code generation and have spent the last 20 minutes or so trying to figure out exactly how to get that going. I gotta say, normally jOOQ docs are great, but I can't make heads or tails of how to implement this correctly. Like, is it H2 only? Or does MySQL work, too? What's the driver for MySQL? It's not what one would define in Spring props...

Just to have it asked: the use of ENTITY_FIELDS as written is not SomeEntity.ENTITY_FIELDS - so there is a static import or the repo is a static inner class?  If the later then try to prefix the class to the field anyway; groovy does not look as strictly for think like Java does and although IDEs with their Java knowledge think it's right, it's not.

"I have to assume that the way we're doing the "table" in from() does provide field lists since it works in certain ways and not others." And how exactly would that work? Your table instance doesn't know its fields, so if you don't pass an explicit list of fields to select(), then jOOQ doesn't know what to project other than *. Generated tables know their fields and would project all of them, but that's still not what you want. I'd use a debugger and step through the query construction. My bet here is that your ENTITY_FIELDS list is empty when you pass it to jOOQ for whatever reason.

Well, this is interesting. I seemingly fixed the issue but implementing a RecordMapper and removing a Map from the repo class. I'll provide details in an answer, but the TL;DR is that the Map caused the imported lists to contain only null elements.

@cfrick, it's statically imported. I've written "a million" of things like this, as have my coworkers, so that's why this behavior has been so strange. Fortunately, a night's sleep (and a refactor to proper implementation) has revealed the cause.

@randy: Ah yes, null elements are ignored by jOOQ, so I was going to suggest this later

This appears to have been due to some random relation/interaction that jOOQ had with a Map field in the repo class. Originally, I added it as a bit of a shortcut because it somehow allowed jOOQ to correctly assign properties in the .fetchOneInto(ResultObject) bit.
This was, of course, in an effort to remove the need to implement a fully-defined RecordMapper.map method. Being that this "result object" has ~111 properties, I really didn't want to have to define every single one...
So, the "shortcut" map was as simple as this:
Map<String, Object> someRandomName = [
    (FIELDS.COL_1): 'col_1',
    (FIELDS.COL_A): 'col_a'
]

Where FIELDS.COL_A is defined on a subclass of SomeEntity. Nothing else was necessary for some "magic" to happen, but as a result of that magic, the ENTITY_FIELDS List suddenly contained only null elements.
What's interesting is that the mere existence of this map seems to cause the issue, even when it's not used, even when the proper RecordMapper.map method is implemented. Even more intriguing is that I can comment COL_1's mapping out and its list is then non-null, but the COL_A class's list remains null-populated, and vice versa.

This is Groovy. I can assure you it's a Map literal. Granted, it's wrong, because it should be Map<Field<?>, String>, but that still results in the same behavior.

Now it is - your previous code use = instead of :
